# Can I release an MVC3 session early

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

Currently, MVC3 synchronizes requests on a user's Session. This means that requests are served one at a time for any particular authenticated client. Is there a method for releasing the session lock earlier from inside an MVC3 controller? There are points in my code where I am finished with the session and I am happy for another request to be served.

I am interested in the session contents at some point, so a sessionless controller doesn't work.

I'd like to manually release the lock on the session to allow the next request to be served. Can this be done without rewriting large portions of the MVC3 session mechanism?